# how to do sql query on drupal7 database to get all records for a "content type "

Tags: drupal-7

I have a drupal7 content type called Programs...like so

```
LABEL   |MACHINE NAME   |FIELD TYPE              |WIDGET             |OPERATIONS
_________________________________________________________________________________ 
Title   |title         |Node module element     

Picture |field_picture |Image                    |Image              |edit  delete

Body    |body          |Long text and summary    |Text area with a summary  |edit   delete

Type of Program |field_type_of_program  |Term reference |Select list    |edit   delete
```

From this content type there are several pages that are authored in Drupal.

I am working on a separate non-drupal webpage that will allow people to register for the programs shown in Drupal, so I want to query the Drupal database to get the information shown by "content type" for Program that has been authored so I can display a list of each program with picture, description, do age checks, validations, etc. How do I do this query? I am confused by how this information is mapped inside the drupal database and I cannot figure out how to write a query to get the info I need.

Comment: I would try and export data you need from drupal to your external page. first to my mind: xml. Or some other technique you maybe confortable with. Basically, let Drupal load nodes for you.

Comment: You could do webservices to achieve that.

Answer (score 0):

[Drupal Services module](https://www.drupal.org/project/services) is you saviour, it requires you to write some code.